# Восстановление данных из одной таблицы после бекапа

Tags: sql

Пред история.
Была БД (test_db), сделали её бэкап.
После бэкапа в одной из таблиц удалили почти миллион данных.
Прошёл месяц. Теперь надо вернуть эти данные назад.
Восстановил ранее сделанный бэкап, в котором эти записи были и развернул его отдельной БД с новым именем (test_db_new).
Запрос на выборку данных из восстановленной таблицы (test_db_new) есть, каким запросом можно ДОБАВИТЬ выбранные данные в таблицу (test_db)?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO test_db_new.table (Column1, Column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM test_db.table
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Копирует и между разными базами, см. тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22912167/5752652

Comment: А зачем `WHERE`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Хотел показать, что там будет какое-то условие, отбирающее удалённые ID'шники, типа id > 100 and id < 200

Comment: Автору надо наоборот - не во временную базу из боевой, а из временной в боевую. *Копирует и между разными базами* - но надо оговориться, что строго в рамках одного инстанса MySQL-сервера. А то был весёлый случай...

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался. Но теперь проблема с полями типа XML.((
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755511/sql-xml-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Так можно из таблицы в удалённой базе в локальную таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO tab (column1, column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM tab@remote_test_db;
```