# SQL XML Ошибка при вставке данных

Tags: sql, xml, insert

Пытаюсь скопировать данные из одной таблицы БД (бекап) в аналогичную таблицу на product БД.
Запрос:

```
INSERT INTO 
        candidates  
SELECT 
        *   
FROM 
        [estaffdb-20171101192519].dbo.candidates
where 
        creation_date < '2017-01-01'
```

Ошибка:
Сообщение 527, уровень 16, состояние 2, строка 1
Implicit conversion between XML types constrained by different XML schema collections is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Ссылка на структуру таблицы
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOyQcj7XPie6ZOokoYcQUit-NESExaJ-AhRPhD7fdHU/edit?usp=sharing

Я правильно понимаю что все поля типа XML, надо обернуть в CONVERT(XML, название_поля )?? Или есть другие варианты?

P.S Насколько опасно запускать вот такой запрос? данных почти миллион.

```
INSERT INTO
    dbo.candidates  
SELECT 
    *,
CONVERT( XML, idata_division_id ),
CONVERT( XML, roles ),
CONVERT( XML, participant_events),
CONVERT( XML, participant_event_group_id),
CONVERT( XML, prev_educations),
CONVERT( XML, passport),
CONVERT( XML, external_registrations),
CONVERT( XML, doc_info),
CONVERT( XML, skills),
CONVERT( XML, idata_citizenship_id),
CONVERT( XML, idata_location_id),
CONVERT( XML, metro_station_id),
CONVERT( XML, idata_source_id),
CONVERT( XML, profession_id),
CONVERT( XML, idata_profession_id),
CONVERT( XML, prev_jobs),
CONVERT( XML, spots),
CONVERT( XML, attachments),
CONVERT( XML, hot_events),
CONVERT( XML, multi_role_id),
CONVERT( XML, external_uids),
CONVERT( XML, desired_division_id),
CONVERT( XML, job_target),
CONVERT( XML, idata_group_id),
CONVERT( XML, multi_attachment_type_id),
CONVERT( XML, exclusive_access)   
FROM 
    [estaffdb-20171101192519].dbo.candidates
WHERE creation_date < '2017-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Типы данных для вставки должны соответствовать типам данных столбцов конечной таблицы. Также должно совпадать число столбцов.

Вот вам пример с такой же ошибкой:

```
declare @xml xml
select @xml = '<x>1</x>'

create table #MyTest (id int, text nvarchar(8))
insert #MyTest 
values
(1,@xml)

select * from #MyTest

drop table #MyTest
```

Comment: Добрый день! 
Спасибо за ответ.
Только я не могу понять как могут отличаться типы данных и кол-во столбцов?
Я копирую данные в таблицу из бэкапа этой таблицы. То есть таблицы одинаковые. Просто в одной есть данные, которых нет в другой ... Из чего следует что колонки тоже одинаковые.

Comment: Ошибка именно из-за приведения типов, пропишите соответствия столбцов, так будет легче найти проблему