# Правильное слияние таблиц sql

Tags: sql, резервное-копирование

День добрый!
Подскажите правильный путь решения проблемы.

Есть база данных ПО для управления кандидатами на работу.
В этой БД есть таблица кандидаты - candidates.
1.11.2017 был сделан полный бекап базы. После чего из таблицы candidates удали все записи у которых дата создания меньше чем 1.01.2017

Сегодня потребовалось вернуть в текущую версию БД, записи из бекапа. То есть не полностью перезалить бекап, а добавить из бэкапа в продуктив ранее удалённые записи таблицы candidates.

Интересует механизм который бы слили две одинаковые таблицы из "Продукта" и "Бэкапа", с учётом всех связей.

Comment: Что значит "с учетом всех связей", если таблица одна, то никаких связей у записей нет и вы можете их спокойно вставлять с помощью `insert ... select`. А если связи есть и участвуют другие таблицы, то каждую таблицу надо будет рассматривать и сливать отдельно

Comment: И чем собственно данный ваш вопрос отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755332/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0

Comment: Он отличается тем, что после такого восстановления ПО не может открыть данные карточки ...

Comment: но на него невозможно ответить, не видя полной структуры вашей БД с данными. Если карточки не открываются, значит информация содержалась не только в этой таблице. А как можно рекомендовать что то сделать, если не известно что это за таблицы. P.S. вам _необходимо_ знать структуру вашей БД на уровне разработчика той программы

Comment: Я просто думал что есть такой механизм для слияния :
1. Указываешь БД откуда брать данные
2. Указываешь БД куда заливать данные.
3. Программа сливает все записи во всех таблицах опираясь на ID в этих таблицах.  Если записи с таким ID нет, то она добавляет, если есть то берём следующую и так далее.

Comment: Если вы выгрузите бекап в виде отдельных запросов insert по всем таблицам и потом его прогоните с игнорированием ошибок то он конечно вставит все записи, которых не оказалось, но я бы не стал делать такого на рабочей БД ни при каких обстоятельствах. вероятность что это не поможет и внесет в БД что то несовместимое очень высока. И боюсь такой программы не существует потому что не все связи в БД очевидны. И не во всех таблицах могут быть установлены достаточные ограничения что бы не допустить дублей

Comment: Для начала я бы просмотрел все foreign key которые ссылаются на ту таблицу, вставка в которую не помогла и попробовал бы узнать что это за таблицы и вставить данные в них. можете попробовать взять MySQL Workbench (идет в комплекте MySQL для windows) (если у вас, конечно, MySQL) и выполнить в нем "Create EER Model from existing database" (там где то в меню и на первой странице должно быть что то подобное) по существующей БД (резервной копии или рабочей) и он вам нарисует структуру БД со всеми связями, из этих связей и надо будет исходить ...

Comment: Там связей тьма тьмущая ... кандидаты связываются с вакансиями, файлами, резюме, руководителями и так далее ...
В общем беда какая то ...